# Python: OSError: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.7, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using the library `misty` for one month and it's working on my personal laptop. But when I am trying to make it work on the another device it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 577, in <module>
    main()
  File "client.py", line 558, in main
    this_device, args.ini.address,
  File "client.py", line 57, in __init__
    MSTPSimpleApplication.__init__(self, *args)
  File "/###/###/venv/lib/python3.7/python3.7/site-packages/misty/mstplib/__init__.py", line 531, in __init__
    self.mux = MSTPMultiplexer(self.localDevice, self.localAddress)
  File "/###/###/venv/lib/python3.7/python3.7/site-packages/misty/mstplib/__init__.py", line 428, in __init__
    self.directPort = MSTPDirector(self.localDevice, self.address)
  File "/###/###/venv/lib/python3.7/python3.7/site-packages/misty/mstplib/__init__.py", line 203, in __init__
    mstp_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(libmstp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /###/###/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/misty/mstplib/libmstp_agent.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in anticipation.